$||Ax|| \leq ||x||_{*} \leq \sqrt{n} ||Ax||_2$
Show that exists a norm $||.||_{*}$ such that for each matrix satisfying $$||Ax||_2 \leq ||x||_{*} \leq \sqrt{n} ||Ax||_2$$
exists a vector $x$ such that $||x||_{*} = \sqrt{n}||Ax||_2$. This is possibly correlated with this question, but I don't feel ellipsoids could play relevant role here. I think it's a more linear algebra type of problem but the most meaningful thing to me could be using the infinity norm, because of the usual $||.||_{2} \leq \sqrt{n} ||.||_{\infty}$ but this doesn't seem to help, since I don't know how to understand the action of $A$.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

What is the norm on the LHS?

The Euclidean sorry it was a typo. @user1551

Take norm 2 with $x=0$.

Yes thanks! Though to be meaningful $x$ has to be non $0$ @Redshoes.
